# Почему использование SVG в ячейке <table> приводит к 100% ширине таблицы?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

Я создаю таблицу, которая должна отображать данные приемлимым образом. И не занимать ширину 100%, если она не нужна.

Проблема в том, что в одном столбце я использую линейную диаграмму, и когда я строю эту диаграмму с помощью div, она работает хорошо, но когда я использую SVG, таблица занимает 100% (я предпочитаю использовать SVG, поскольку он более гибкий).

Ниже показано, как должна выглядеть таблица (и это выглядит так, если использовать div вместо SVG для отображения линейной диаграммы):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И вот так таблица выглядит при использовании SVG, занимая всю ширину страницы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я предполагаю, что это потому, что SVG пытается захватить как можно больше места и раздувает таблицу до 100%.

**Как это можно  исправить?**
Я использую **фиксированный макет таблицы и фиксированную процентную ширину столбца.** Я не знаю заранее данные, которые будут отображаться в таблице, и ширину таблицы, таблица должна автоматически определять оптимальную ширину.

Упрощенный пример:

```css
table { table-layout: fixed; max-wdith: 100% }
tr > * { border: 1px solid black; }
svg { display: block; }

</table>
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th style="width: 50%;">a</th>
    <th style="width: 50%;">b</th>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>
      <svg height="1rem" width="100%">
        <rect x="0%" y="25%" width="100%" height="50%" fill="black"/>
      </svg>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

P.S.

Один из возможных способов исправить это - сначала скрыть линейные графики SVG и позволить визуализировать таблицу без SVG. А затем через 1 мс или около того, когда таблица будет отрисована, измерить ширину таблицы и явно установить ее с помощью JS. Затем отобразите строки SVG, и таблица будет ограничена явной шириной, измеренной ранее.
Но, может быть, есть способ попроще?

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Why using SVG in  cell forces table to 100% width?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68184519/7394871) от участника  [@Alex Craft](https://stackoverflow.com/users/231624/alex-craft).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/68184519/7394871

Answer (score 1):

Вот способ, чтобы отключить влияние SVG на ширину. Вы просто устанавливаете `width: 0` и добавляете
`min-width: 100%`, чтобы снова восстановить полную ширину:

Он должен работать на вашем реальном примере (я тестировал)

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  max-wdith: 100%
}

tr>* {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

svg {
  display: block;
  width:0;
  min-width:100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th style="width:50%;">aaa</th>
    <th style="width:50%;">bbb</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>
      <svg height="1rem" >
        <rect x="0%" y="25%" width="100%" height="50%" fill="black"/>
      </svg>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th style="width:50%;">aaa</th>
    <th style="width:50%;">bbbbbbb</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>
      <svg height="1rem">
        <rect x="0%" y="25%" width="100%" height="50%" fill="black"/>
      </svg>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Связанный вопрос: [How to match width of text to width of dynamically sized image/title?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55040250/8620333)

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68185156/7394871) от участника  [@Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif).</sub>